# How would I format a query that depends on post parent taxonomy

Tags: wp-query, wpdb

I'm trying to do a custom query which is outside the scope of a single `WP_Query`, I think I should be using `$wpdb` but my SQL is a bit ropey. Also I only need the post IDs returned not post objects.

Basically I need to find all posts with a meta value of `$foobar` whose parent post has one or more specific terms. I.E:

GET all `my_custom_post_type` posts
IF their `postmeta` has a field `my_custom_field` with a value `$foobar`
AND their `post_parent` has the `my_custom_tax` terms `foo` & `bar`
RETURN the post's IDs as an array.

Any pointers would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Use a `get_posts` query for that

Comment: @PieterGoosen They're all custom post types so do use both post parents and taxonomies. Using get_posts I can't query the parent's taxonomy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still use `get_posts`:

```
$parents = get_posts(
    array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type'      => 'my_custom_post_type',
        'fields'         => 'ids', // Just get IDs, not objects
        'tax_query'      => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'my_custom_tax',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => array(
                    'foo',
                    'bar',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    )
);

$post_ids = get_posts(
    array(
        'posts_per_page'  => -1,
        'post_parent__in' => $parents,
        'post_type'       => 'my_custom_post_type',
        'fields'          => 'ids',
        'meta_query'       => array(
            array(
                'key'   => 'my_custom_field',
                'value' => $foobar,
            ),
        ),
    )
);
```

Further reading on [tax queries](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) and [meta queries](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query).

Comment: Fantastic. Seems so obvious now! I guess I was overthinking it trying to wrap it up in a single query. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @TheDeadMedic, im stuck with a problem. Would be very kind of you if you look into it. Thank you so much https://stackoverflow.com/q/66519311/9036446